# Movies database software

Tags: video, collection-manager

I have a certain amount of movies stored on my computer and I would like to have a database containing information about these movies.

The database should be filled with metadata from [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/) or other free movie databases. My movies are all named "title (4 digits year).avi".

I tried [EMDB](http://www.emdb.tk/) (for Windows) but it doesn't recognize the pattern I used to name files, so I should fill it by myself one movie by one.

Is there a software to which I can tell what is the pattern of the names of my movies so it can automatically find the metadata about each movie?

It should run on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a software to which I can tell what is the pattern of the
>   names of my movies so it can automatically find the metadata about
>   each movie?

Suggest that you look into using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) via any of the scripting language or hundreds of tools for doing this to change the current file naming pattern to match the one required by EMDB.

For example, [Powerful GREP](http://www.powergrep.com/) has a free trial that might work for your needs, and likely would not require you to learn much to get the job done. If you're having a hard time figuring out the pattern EMDB needs and the one you're currently using, you likely could get an answer to this problem on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), though you'd need to let people know the version of RegEx (regular expression) you're using and language if you're not using Power GREP.

---

If it's of use, here's the file naming file naming conventions used by EMDB:

> **[EMDB V2.29     March 18th, 2015](http://www.emdb.eu/history.htm)**
>
> IMDb Search: Improved the IMDb search matching algorithm. EMDB now
>   fully follows the Kodi/XBMC media file naming conventions
>   (http://kodi.wiki/view/Naming_video_files/Movies) e.g. "Avatar
>   (2009).mkv". Multiple files should be extended with "-cd1", "-cd2"
>   etc. to automatically convert them to playlists.

Answer (score 1):

[Movie Explorer](http://www.zeropaid.com/news/99269/movie-explorer-organize-yourhuge-movie-collections-with-details-from-imdb/): Organize Your Huge Movie Collection with Details from IMDb
You can download program [here](https://github.com/anlarke/MovieExplorer/releases).
 Download MovieExplorer084a-64bit.zip or MovieExplorer084a-32bit.zip depending on your Windows. (I have 64-bit version and it runs smooth on Windows 7). Unzip it. Then run it and close it. The program will create Database.xml file. Right-click on it and open with Wordpad or Notepad, then edit the Directory path.

I hope it will work for you :)

Comment: Seems nice, but you cannot specify the pattern of the file name of the movie, neither the language of the title of the movie.

Answer (score 0):

[Smovault](http://smovault.blogspot.com/p/features.html) is a software that should work for you.
It is *free* for personal use.
It uses [TMDb](https://www.themoviedb.org/) to download movie data like cast, crew, posters, etc and also provides movie recommendations based on your taste.
It has a bulk import feature which requires folders to be named similar to a movie, which it then searches for correct movie match on TMDb. It does all of this in a user friendly manner.

[DISCLOSURE] - I am the developer of Smovault.